# Play audio From URL when click on a Button inside TableViewCell

Tags: uitableview, button, objective-c-blocks, avaudioplayer

My tableView Method is

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    wordsTableViewCell *cell;
    if (cell==nil)
    {
        cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    }
    cell.wordIndexlbl.layer.masksToBounds = true;
    cell.wordIndexlbl.layer.cornerRadius = 8;
    cell.redWord.text= [self.wordsFromArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.blueWord.text=[self.words objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.wordIndexlbl.text=[self.wordsID objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.playCell.tag=indexPath.row;
    [cell.playCell addTarget:self action:@selector(playURLCell:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    return cell;

}
```

and then i make a button action and method to call function like this

```
- (IBAction)playURLCell:(UIButton *)sender
{
    UIButton *senderButton=(UIButton *)sender;
    NSLog(@"current row = %ld" , (long)senderButton.tag);
    [self getWord:_uppercaseString For:_combinedStirng String:wordIndex];
}
-(void)getWord:(NSString*)upperCaseString For:(NSString *)combinedString String:(NSString *)wordIndex
{
    BOOL isInternetAvailable = [[NetworkManager sharedInstance] check];

    if (isInternetAvailable)
    {

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void){

            NSData *data;
            NSString *urlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://quicklanguages.com/materiales/quicklanguages/audios/%@/%@-%@.mp3",upperCaseString,combinedString,wordIndex];
            NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:urlStr];
             [playURLArray addObject:url];
            data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [self playAudio:data];
            });
        });
    }
}
-(void)playAudio :(NSData *)data
{
    audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:data error:nil]; // Now we are assigning it in an instance variable thus ARC will not deallocate it.

    audioPlayer.delegate=self;
    [audioPlayer play];
}
```

when I click on button inside from cell , audio not playing and wordIndex goes nill 
no error comes what is the problem any one help me

please tell my problem

Answer (score 0):

You have some conceptual errors in code.
I will give you some tips to work better.

a) at:

```
 [cell.playCell addTarget:self action:@selector(playURLCell
```

You are adding an action to a cell OR to a button?
b) if you have a button, (as You did for other elements, as labels..) add action to it.

c) better to make a custom cell (I see you create a class "wordsTableViewCell", pls use WordsTableViewCell for classes..) AND load it from a separate XIB.

d) do not call dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier conditionally if nil.. (see code Xcode creates for you for a new TableViewController)
simply use:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    WordsTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...  
    return cell;
}
```

e) make some preparation settings and action in "awakeFromNib":

```
@implementation WordsTableViewCell

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
    // Initialization code
    // set buttons or prepare labels... (or use action from IB..)
}
```

(labels will be filled up as You already do in cellForRowAtIndexPath)

f) better to use a protocol to let CONTROLLER play (or make the code inside custom code, in the action, but ugly (see below))

g) keep in mind cells are reused so you loose EVERYTHING you have setup when recycled.

**h) last but NOT least:**
code fails as in:

```
-(void)playAudio :(NSData *)data
{
    audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:data error:nil]; // Now we are assigning it in an instance variable thus ARC will not deallocate it.

    audioPlayer.delegate=self;
    [audioPlayer play];
}
```

As audioPlayer will be released by ARC, so audio stops.
So you must KEEP an AVAudioPlayer instance alive: a viable solution is to put it in Controller.
Let's see the steps:

a) create a protocol, let's say

DidTapToPlayProtocol:

```
@protocol DidTapToPlayProtocol <NSObject>
@required
-(void)didTapToPlay:(NSInteger)tag;
@end
```

b)
in custom cell *.h (WordsTableViewCell.h) import protocol and  declare a delegate:

```
  #import "DidTapToPlayProtocol.h"

@interface WordsTableViewCell : UITableViewCell

    @property (weak, nonatomic) id <DidTapToPlayProtocol>didTapDelegate;

@end
```

c) in controller, set delegate or cell:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    WordsTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...

    cell.didTapDelegate = self;

    return cell;
}
```

d) in button action call:

```
 -(IBAction)play:(UIButton *)sender {

    NSInteger tag ... // get tag..
    [self.didTapDelegate didTapToPlay:tag];

}
```

e) in Table view controller *h allocate a data member:

```
 @interface MyTableViewController : UITableViewController

    @property (string, nonatomic) AVAudioPlayer* audioPlayer;

@end
```

and set it in delegate callback: (now will be retained. Note: we can use a better approach... allocating in in ViewDidLoad.. anyway..)

```
- (void)didTapToPlay:(NSInteger)tag{

    NSData * data;
    .....
    self.audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:data error:nil];
}
```

(I have written a base code.. if need zip let me know..)

Comment: Thanks for this kind reply , but alreday i solved this problem